# How to position a pop up div like the profile info on this site

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, css

I'm trying to do a pop up div like the ones that show up when you hover over your username or click the StackExchange words on the top most tool bar on this site.

I'm not asking for the ajax code etc. Just how to position it. I looked at their code using firebug, but they don't specify a position like x 250 y 500. So how do these guys get it to appear just under the username or StackExchange letters?

Comment: There is absolute position there if you inspect the top level div for the popover.

Comment: Take the actual position of the mouse and there show a div with whatever you like inside and set the style to `position:absolute` `top: here put the 'x' of the mouse` `left:here put the 'y'` ... or do this with the `onmouseover` event handler of the div you want to show the popup and get the position of the div to put there the popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v27kT/). Does it help?

Actually, you can do it without JavaScript at all, the itea of using javascript is to suspend the `hide` of the popup

Comment: I was working things out and you already finished it.

Comment: what you mean? this is not what you wanted?

Comment: Oh No. This is perfect. I'll take it further from here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow clearly uses JavaScript to achieve the effect of how the popup appears. A little jQuery ( $('#mydiv').show(100); ) will do this for you). You can achieve a similar effect using only CSS with the adjacent sibling selector, like this:

```
div {display: none;}

a:hover + div { display: block;}
```

The positioning of the 'popup' element is achieved within a central page div with its margin set to "0 auto". The topbar is placed within this element, with its width set to "100%" and its position set to "relative". Declaring a div's position as relative allows you to absolutely position child elements relative to the parent element, rather than relative to the entire page.

To get your absolutely positioned popup div to appear below your topbar link, simply set the div's "top" attribute to the pixel height of the topbar div, and its "right" attribute to the appropriate pixel value to place it beneath your link.  You can do this dynamically with jQuery like so, assuming your link is a block-level element:

```
var offset = $('#myLink').offset(); 

var newLeft = offset.x; 

var newRight = offset.y + $('#myLink').width(); 

$('#popup').css({

   left : newLeft,
   right : newRight
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What they've done is an absolute position, when you click or hover the element, the pop up goes from display none to display block. the positioning is controlled by float (float left). the x positioning is made relative to other elements. In this case the header element is 960px wide and then centered using margin:auto. so the pop-up will appear to the left of the header element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` on the actual popup, and use `position: relative` on the parent container where you place it. That way you can position it to the container, which will be where you place the actual click event div.